# Get a list of a certain context with owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts_as_taggabe_on and I'm working with two contexts. My models are:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  acts_as_tagger 
end

class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags, :projects
end
```

Now in my controller... with @company.owned_tags I have tags for both contexts of the owner @company. How to get tags for the project context of the owner @company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on rails 2.x

```
@company.owned_tags.all(:conditions => ["context = ?", "project"])
```

on rails 3

```
@company.owned_tags.all.where("context = ?", "project")
```

Basically the owned_tags is just an activerecord relationship.

Comment: Mmmmh, context isn't an attribute of tags table, is an attribute of taggings table...

Comment: did you try it because owned_tags needs to connect to taggings this is why it works!

Comment: Something was wrong in my code but... yes it works in this way: @company.owned_tags.where("context = ?", "projects"). Thank you!